# Accesing XAMPP MySql Database from Another Computer

Tags: php, mysql, xampp

So a friend of mine and I are using both xampp on ubuntu, if that helps, to connect between each other's website, We both created the same php file to connect, so we use de IP of the other, but then it says an error

```
Warning: mysql_connect() [function.mysql-connect]: Host 'coke-laptop.local' is not allowed to connect to this MySQL server in /opt/lampp/htdocs/connection.php on line 2
Could not connect: Host 'coke-laptop.local' is not allowed to connect to this MySQL server
```

We have this code on the connection.php file:

```
<?php
$link = mysql_connect('10.100.161.37','root','');
if (!$link) {
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}
//echo 'Connected successfully';

$db_selected = mysql_select_db('Prueba', $link);
if (!$db_selected) {
    die ('Can\'t use Prueba : ' . mysql_error());
}

// This could be supplied by a user, for example
$firstname = 'fred';
$lastname  = 'fox';

// Formulate Query
// This is the best way to perform an SQL query
// For more examples, see mysql_real_escape_string()
$query = sprintf("SELECT * FROM Agencia");

// Perform Query
$result = mysql_query($query);

// Check result
// This shows the actual query sent to MySQL, and the error. Useful for debugging.
if (!$result) {
    $message  = 'Invalid query: ' . mysql_error() . "\n";
    $message .= 'Whole query: ' . $query;
    die($message);
}

// Use result
// Attempting to print $result won't allow access to information in the resource
// One of the mysql result functions must be used
// See also mysql_result(), mysql_fetch_array(), mysql_fetch_row(), etc.
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    echo $row['ID'] . " ";
    echo $row['Nombre'] . "\n\r";
}

// Free the resources associated with the result set
// This is done automatically at the end of the script
mysql_free_result($result);
mysql_close($link);
?>
```

If we use the IP just like that, we can enter each others xampp normal welcome page.

Comment: Have you given `coke-laptop.local` access to the database? I.e. there is a user for that host that can access the database?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Check you have enabled remote access to the MySQL server.  Open the my.cnf file  (probably found inside xampp/etc/), go to the `[mysqld]` section and add the following (using your own ip address instead of the example)

```
bind-address=192.168.1.100
```

If there is a line that says `skip-networking`, comment that out so it looks like this:

```
# skip-networking
```

then restart the MySQL server

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your MySQL database isn't allowing you to connect remotely with the credentials you provided.  You will need to configure a remote user to connect.  Try looking into [MySQL Grants](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/grant.html).

For Example:

```
GRANT SELECT, INSERT ON database.* TO 'someuser'@'somehost';
```