# Use one local MySQL database from different PCs on LAN

Tags: php, mysql, xampp

I have a PHP-MySQL application and I want to use one database from different PCs. I got my answer in this question someone asked: [Accesing XAMPP MySql Database from Another Computer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3507205/accesing-xampp-mysql-database-from-another-computer?rq=1).

Now the problem is that they mentioned `my.cnf` file to edit but I don't have such a file in my xampp folder. Is there any other file we can edit for these settings?

Comment: take a look at the xampp/mysql/bin folder. You sure there is no my.cnf file?

Comment: @LouisH. ya sure there is no .cnf file in the entire xampp folder. In xampp/mysql/bin i have one configuration file my.ini

Comment: That's the same file, just using another extension.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got the answer and I tested also how to access one PC MySQL database from different PCs on LAN :)

you just need to put the `IP` of that PC where you install your `MySQL server`. For example

```
192.168.1.3/xampp/ OR 192.168.1.3/my_php_project/index.php
```

In the above link `192.168.1.3` is the `IP` of the PC where `MySQL server` is installed

Answer (score 0):

This could help you :

http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/how-do-i-enable-remote-access-to-mysql-database-server.html

After that, your mysql user must allow that kind of connection (the server has to be set to '%'). Check the SQL command:

```
GRANT ALL ON foo.* TO bar@’%’ IDENTIFIED BY ‘PASSWORD’;
```

Comment: I ask in my question that i don't have my.cnf file in my xampp folder, and the link you send me talking about my.cnf file settings... so how can i change these setting even if i dont have my.cnf