# retrieve data from mysql database using php from a different computer

Tags: php, mysql, xampp

I am a newbie on PHP . Can someone tell me how to connect and retrieve data from mysql database server using PHP from a different computer.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Accesing XAMPP MySql Database from Another Computer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3507205/accesing-xampp-mysql-database-from-another-computer)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, the MySQL server must accept remote connections.

Also MySQL's user that you use, must be allowed to log from PHP computer's IP.

Then you can simply connect from your PHP server changing configuration of connection by setting host parameter to MySQL server's IP instead of localhost.

Google for `mysql remote connection` in order to find information about how to configure it to accept remote connections.

Comment: do i have to use a ssh tunnel ?

Answer (score 0):

Localhost in name suggest locally , you cannot access mysql database from another computer . 
Copy the file and install , only then it will work.