# Will my database connection (connected using Netbeans and XAMPP) work on a different pc?

Tags: java, database, netbeans, phpmyadmin, xampp

Program and database connection was made in Netbeans, and I can access my database using localhost/phpMyadmin/.

Since I need to put the program in a disc for a project, I made an installer for the java program so I can access it directly and won't have to open it through Netbeans. I used Install Creator for this. When I installed the Java program on my pc, it works, both the GUI and database content shows up.

Now my concern is, I need install the java program in a different pc. Will the database connection work? So far, I've only installed the program on the other pc and only the GUI shows up. If I install XAMPP on the other pc, will the database content show up on my program?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Accesing XAMPP MySql Database from Another Computer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3507205/accesing-xampp-mysql-database-from-another-computer)

Comment: What is the purpose of deploying the solution to the other computer?

Answer (score 0):

What kind of a `DBMS` are you using? You should install that `DBMS` on the other PC, plus `JVM` to make your program work.

When you write a program for other machines, you should install all the dependencies as well.

Answer (score 0):

The connection will work if you configure it properly.

Your database content will not show up on the other computer, unless the other computer has a connection to your previous computer and can access it's database. Which it *probably* does not have (or does it?). However if the connection would be possible you would obviously need to configure it in your application.

Assuming there is no connection between the two computers, you probably need to backup the database content manually and restore it on the new computer's database as soon as you install the database there. This will of course be a new *separate* db instance and *copy* of original data set.